# Как подключить код из другой ф-ции?

Tags: django

```
def module_post():

    return data_user = '30 лет'



def post(request):

    user = 'Maria_001'

    module_post()

    return render(request, 'site/post.html', {'data' : data_user, 'user' : user, }
```

Я долго копался в интернете, но в результате, ничего толком не вышло. Заранее прошу прощения, если вопрос тупой, но я и сам рассчитывал его решить в одиночку за не продолжительное время. Но я только разбираюсь с Джангой, так что прошу не судить строго... Благодарю!

Comment: `def module_post():

    return '30 лет'` и `{'data' : module_post(), ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот:

```
def post(request):
  user = 'Maria_001'
  data = module_post()
  return render(request, 'site/post.html', {'user': user, 'data': data})
```

Comment: Благодарю, ступил)